# Downloading a mail as pdf using imaplib module in python

Tags: python, email, imaplib

```
mail.login(email_username, email_password)
mail.select('Inbox')
result, data = mail.search(None, '(FROM "abc@gmail.com" SUBJECT "Hello")' )
ids = data[0]
```

After searching for a particular mail from mail inbox, I want to download the mail as pdf. I've looked elsewhere, but I could only find parsing mail content using get_payload() method. Is there any module in python to save the mail as we manually do by clicking on print button in gmail? Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Most email is HTML, so chucking in **any HTML-to-PDF converter** from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23359083/2111778) works.

I also swapped out `imaplib` for `imap_tools` for you because it has an easier API:

```py
import pdfkit
from imap_tools import MailBox

with MailBox('imap.gmail.com').login(email_username, email_password, 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    for i, msg in enumerate(mailbox.fetch('ALL', limit=10)):
        html = '<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>' + \
               msg.html
        pdfkit.from_string(html, str(i) + '.pdf')
```

**Notes:**

- `pdfkit` does not handle non-ASCII [unless you add a utf-8 header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7367200/2111778) like I did
- Some messages might not have HTML content, use `msg.html or msg.text` for them
- I installed Chocolatey, then used choco to install wkhtmltopdf (pdfkit dependency)
- I am using GMail, which requires turning on less secure apps [here](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1) ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33119667/2111778))

**Results (this is from 2012):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [ReportLab](https://pypi.org/project/reportlab/) to create a pdf file with the content you get from the `get_payload()` method